# Does Memgraph support Resource Description Framework (RDF)?

Tags: rdf, memgraphdb

I have data in one RDF project. I'd like to transfer it to Memgraph. Does Memgraph support Resource Description Framework (RDF)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph doesn't include a tool that would allow you direct data import from RDF.

You need to define mappings, connect to Memgraph with any of the clients and run appropriate Cypher queries for database creation. You can use a labeled property graph model that is represented by a set of nodes, relationships, properties and labels. Then you need to map the RDF statement to those nodes, relationships and properties.